# How to correctly override and enhance property

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Code tells more than words, so look at this:

```
public abstract class ViewObject: INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public virtual string Id {
    get {
      return this.GetType().Name;
    }
  }
}

public class Object : ViewObject {
  private string id = string.Empty;
  public override string Id {
    get {
      return this.id;
    }
    set {
      this.id = value;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to implement the desired behaviour of a base implementation in the abstract class (yes, it should have a base implementation for this, but not for other things)?

I can only think of using the `new` keywork instead of `override` to simply hide the base implementation, but is this right?

Answer (score 0):

you are already using inheritance. Override method is useful when method name and parameter is same.
here you can use method overloading.
for method overload  name is same but parameter is different. you can use in inheritance also. 
i hope this is useful

Answer (score -1):

If you use the `new` keyword and someone casts your derived object to the base class, the base implementation will be called and not the derived one. To avoid this, the `override` is needed.

But that is currently not possible, cause your base class doesn't support a setter. So stick to the `override` and implement a `set` method in the base class that simply throws a `NotSupportedExecption`.

```
public abstract class ViewObject
{
    public virtual string Id
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
}

public class Object : ViewObject
{
    private string id = string.Empty;
    public override string Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id = value; }
    }
}
```